# Testing with functions passed to a mock object

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a simple function which was recently wrapped by some additional logic. I am struggling with updating the test logic since suddently, the method body is wrapped in a mock.

Let me give you an example.

Former logic & test:

```
// logic
public void doSomething(Transaction t, int a) {
  myService.foo(t, a);
}
```

And my test:

```
// test
TestedService service;

@Mock
MyService myService;

@Mock
Transaction t;

@Test
public void testSomething() {
   testedService.doSomething(t, 10);
   Mockito.verify(myService).foo(t, 10);
}
```

What happened is that we wrapped our logic in some additional function:

```
public void doSomething(Transaction t, int a) {
   model.runInEnhancedTransaction(t, t2 -> { myService.foo(t2, a) });
}
```

My question is, how do I test this when the logic is suddently wrapped in in `model` method (model is a mock in my test).

I basically need to verify that `t2 -> { myService.foo(t2, a) }` was called when the `model` object is a mock.

EDIT: I made it work with implementing my custom version of `model` just for the test purpose but still wonder if there is some more elegant way.

Comment: Where is the `model` coming from?

Comment: It's just another service injected in the class, same way as `MyService`. In test, it is a mock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of tough to test these kinds of lambda invocations. What I do is perform two tests: one that `model.runInEnhancedTransaction()` was called, and one for `model.runInEnhancedTransaction()` itself. eg

```
@Test
void doSomethingCallsModelEnhancedTransaction() {
    testedService.doSomething(t, 10);
    verify(model).runInEnhancedTransaction(eq(t), any());
}
@Test
void modelRunInEnhancedTransaction() {
    Transaction t = mock(Transaction.class);
    BiConsumer<Transaction, Integer> consumer = mock(Biconsumer.class);
    model.runInEnhancedTransaction(t, consumer);
    verify(consumer).accept(...);
}
```